# Calling function within function using pointers - C

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-address

I have one function that accepts two pointer arguments. Lets say this is

```
void add(u16 *x, u16 *y)
```

And i have another function that accepts three pointer arguments.

```
void fact(u16 *a, u16 *b, u16 *c){
    if(*c > 500){
        add(*a,*b); // Is this correct?
    }
}
```

If a certain criterion within fact is met, I want to pass the arguments a and b to the function add, but I want to pass them by reference, not by value. How exactly can I do this?. a, b, c, x, and y are all passed down from "main" using "&x", when calling the function.

So I want everything to be passed down by reference so that any value modifications will go back to main.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> add(*a,*b); // Is this correct?

No it's not correct.

Given the prototype being `void add(u16 *x, u16 *y)`, then the calling function should call the parameters with the types that match. In `fact()`, `a` and `b` are already pointers, so the correct code should look like:

```
void fact(u16 *a, u16 *b, u16 *c){
    if(*c > 500){
        add(a,b); // this is correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. I personally find it's easier to understand if you write the `*` next to the type and not the variable name.

Your function `add` takes two arguments, both are pointers to `u16`, that is, they are `u16*`. In your `fact`, you have three variables all of which are `u16*`. The types already match, so you need to call it as:

```
add(a, b);
```

You're then passing the *pointer* by value, which is equivalent to passing the actual integer value by reference. You can pass a pointer to a pointer when you need to, but it's less common than passing a pointer by value.